# filter to schedule meetings using DateTime in Genexus

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd, genexus-gam, genexus-dbret

I started programming a little while ago and started a project on genexus to schedule meetings for a company, which needs rules so as not to have appointments at the same times.
I made the rules using date and they were working, but when I switched to datetime they don't work anymore. I dont know Genexus syntax for that, if anyone can help with this I would appreciate it.

```
do case
        case (LocacaoInicio <= &DTInicio and LocacaoFinal >= &DTInicio)
            or (LocacaoInicio <= &DTFinal and LocacaoFinal >= &DTFinal)
            &MensagemValidacao2 = 'Error'
            
        case (LocacaoInicio >= &DTInicio and LocacaoFinal <= &DTInicio)
            or (LocacaoInicio >= &DTInicio and LocacaoFinal <= &DTFinal)
            &MensagemValidacao2 = 'Error'
            
        case (LocacaoInicio < &DTFinal and LocacaoFinal < &DTFinal)
            or (LocacaoInicio > &DTInicio and LocacaoFinal > &DTInicio)
            &MensagemValidacao2 = 'ERROR'
            
        case (LocacaoInicio > &DTFinal and LocacaoFinal > &DTFinal)
            or (LocacaoInicio < &DTInicio and LocacaoFinal < &DTInicio)
            &MensagemValidacao2 = 'Error '
    endcase
```

```
translation of attributes and variables
locacaoinicio = InicialDate
locacaofinal = FinalDate
&mensagemvalidacao2 = &validationMassege
&DTFinal = &DateTimeFinal
&DTInicio = &DateTimeInicio
```

Comment: Are you storing values on the Time part of the attributes and variables? What were the values of the Date attributes/values when they worked and what are the values now that they have changed to DateTime?

Comment: What are the attributes datatype? Did you change it to DateTime too or have you left it on Date?
Possibly you might have to cast your &DT variables to Date or change your attributes datatype to match it.
If possible, could you please be more specific on what error exactly is occurring? (if any) Like a syntax error, java generation error...